# PHP gearman connection error

Tags: php, gearman

I trying to run a task in PHP using gearman I created 2 scripts:
client.php

```
<?
$mail = array(
  'to' => 'test@gmail.com',
  'subject' => Hi',
  'body' => 'Test message',
);


# Connect to Gearman server
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer('127.0.0.1', '4730');


# Send message
$client->doBackground('sendmail', json_encode($mail));
```

worker.php

```
<?php
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();

$worker->addFunction('sendmail', 'send_mail');

while (1)
{
  $worker->work();
  if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) break;
}

function send_mail($job)
{
  $workload = $job->workload();
  $data = json_decode($workload, true);

  mail($data['to'], $data['subject'], $data['body']);
}
```

when I run my worker from comand line : php worker.php &

and run my client.php file I get the below error:

GearmanClient::doBackground(): send_packet(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT) Failed to send server-options packet -> libgearman/connection.cc:485

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: I would explicitly define server on the worker side as well. `$worker->addServer('127.0.0.1', '4730');`.

Comment: Is your gearman server running? check with 'ps awux |grep gearmand'

Comment: I get this when running your command: root      4515  0.0  0.0 103308   880 pts/0    S+   05:49   0:00 grep gearmand

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

`$client->addServer('127.0.0.1', '4730');`

to

`$client->addServer();`

If still no working, try to take a look in the [get started](http://gearman.org/getting-started/) page of this [tutorial](http://gearman.org/getting-started/) on php. It worked fine for me

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to start gearman by running `gearmand -d`

Read more about it in the documentation at http://gearman.org/getting-started/